# Observed groovy compilation error on timestamp function of jmeter during script override option

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

On JSR223 postprocessor of JMeter, I imported the groovy script in script override box. In the script, I'm trying to calculate the timestamp and the jmeter function is added to determine it.

But timestamp function is throwing groovy compilation error during execution. the same code works fine when I give the code in the script box.

Below is the error on the same:

```
Script44.groovy: 30: unexpected token: , @ line 30, column 32.
   String Time = ${__timeShift(,,,,)};
                                  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JMeter function inside JSR223 script, use code, in your case replace timeShift with

```
  java.util.Date.getTime()
```